# Can you use the same plugin twice?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is it possible to use the same plugin twice in a single site. If yes how can I do that. I was thinking by changing the name of the plugin. For instance, seo-plugin.zip would be the right name if I change it to plugin-seo.zip will it work? Or I have to do something else. If you have knowledge about this please share. Thank you!

It is good to know that the reason why I want to use the same plugin twice is because there is a plugin that have two option that I would love to use, but you can only use one option. So, it would be smart to get the same option using the same plugin.

Comment: Yes you can (rename the directory and run both), why can you test this yourself? You don't chnage the name of the plugin this way, so having two plugin with the same name can be confusing. I also expect that your solution not works, be cause of both version will save the option under the same name, so i you change the option for plugin1, you also change it for plugin2. Better rewrite the plugin, so that you can use both option.

Comment: I am not sure of the 'run both' where do I get this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Because of how programming languages work, loading the same plugin twice will result in both versions trying to define the same functions and classes. PHP won't stand for that, and will die with a fatal error.